# Parsing the closest number from any cell preceding it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Simplifying, for clarity: I would like each cell in a column to parse, from any cells above it, the closest cell with a number in it, and then add 1 to it. The cells above may be blank, or may contain letters in addition to numbers, but once it finds a cell with a number, it should take that number and add 1.

---

I have a sheet in which each row represents an item. Many of these items are numbered (sequential, increasing by 1), but some are not. Some also are subdivided, aka, 5a and 5b. For example:

```
1
2

3


4
5a
5b
```

I would like the column of numbers to auto populate, increasing by 1 over the most recent number used. Of course, it cant be tied to the cell number, as there may be blank cells (inserted manually, by deleting the cell value). The way I would like it to work, if I were to insert a new row and give it it's number (ie, not a blank one), I would expect all the numbers below it to then increase by 1 to accommodate.

The sub-numbers (5a, 5b, etc) would be inserted manually, instead of having a formula in the cell. But the cells below it should parse out the number (being 5) to then increment on it (as in, the next cell being 6, so long as I do not make it blank). I will not have to worry about these manually sub-numbered cells updating if something in a row above changes — once it's received a subnumber, we can assume nothing above will change.

Essentially, each cell in the column should run backwards through the cells above it until it parses a number (n), and then display n+1.

How could I accomplish something like this?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455), which make the question useless for others or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following corresponds with your requirements:

- Enter the value 1 in A1
- In A2, enter the following formula: `=regexextract(to_text(chooserows(tocol(A$1:A1,1),-1)),"\d+")+1`
- Drag-copy this formula down the column to the end of the sheet

The mixed reference A$1:A1 expands as you go down the column to include all cells above the cell in question. TOCOL with argument 1 filters out any blanks in the range, then CHOOSEROWS with argument -1 extracts the last cell. REGEXEXTRACT can be used to extract the number portion of cells of the format '1a' (which is strictly interpreted as a text string) but cannot work on pure number cells so TO_TEXT is required to force whatever value is present to a string. We can then just add one to this value (the + operator automatically coerces the text output of REGEXEXTRACT back into a number value).

If you then delete values in the resultant column of numbers and/or modify values to include a/b/etc. then the cells below the change automatically respond.